# Views in ScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to create a `UIScrollView` programatically. I have a `scrollView` for that ViewController. Here is how I instantiate it in `loadView`:

```
    CGRect fullScreenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

I then some items onto it, and then add it to `view` in `loadView` as follows:

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.searchBar];
[self.scrollView addSubview:button];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

So far everything should be fine. However, in other functions, I will be adding `ImageViews` and then I will need to set the scrollview's content size. The way I do it is just use `[self.scrollView addToSubView:image]` and when I want to edit the content size of the scrollview, I do it as follows:

```
// Calculate scroll view size
float sizeOfContent = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [self.scrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
    UIImageView *view =[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    sizeOfContent += view.frame.size.height;
    [view release];
}

// Set content size for scroll view
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent);
```

I keep getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in the main.m class.

I suspect that the problem is with retaining the actual scrollView since I think `scrollView` is not retaining the same object that is a subview of view.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined `self.scrollView` as `@property(nonatomic, retain)` then first wrong thing is the line;

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
```

It sets the retain count of scrollView to 2, which is not what you expect. `alloc` retained properties like this,

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
```

I think your BAD_ACCESS error comes from here;

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.scrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
   UIImageView *view =[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
   sizeOfContent += view.frame.size.height;
   [view release];
}
```

Why are you `releasing` view? You did not `alloc` it, so there is no reason to `release` it. Remove the `[view release]` line and check again.

Comment: So should I create a local scrollview and then just set it to the global scrollview and release the local one?

Comment: @Nayefc yes that is also fine, in fact this way is preferred.